# Mongoose does not seem to recognize the Number type

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am playing around with the mongoose documentation: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html
For some unknown reason to me, the code below does not run, it gives out the error:

```
TypeError: Invalid value for schema path `integerOnly.type`, got value "undefined"
```

If I change the type to String, like, it works:

```
var numberSchema = new Schema({
  integerOnly: {
    type: String,
    get: v => Math.round(v),
    set: v => Math.round(v),
    alias: "i"
  }
});
```

Does anyone can point out what is happening? I have found the mongoose documentation outdated, it seems that they do not update the documentation.

The original code, as in the mongoose page, is below.

```
//--------------------------------------------------

require("./connection");

var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//---------------------------------------------------

var numberSchema = new Schema({
  integerOnly: {
    type: Number,
    get: v => Math.round(v),
    set: v => Math.round(v),
    alias: "i"
  }
});

var Number = mongoose.model("Number", numberSchema);
```

Detail. if I comment out the line `var Number = mongoose.model("Number", numberSchema);`, it gives no error, but I cannot work without defining a model!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a good night of sleep, my beauty sleep, I have found the problem:

```
var numberSchema = new Schema({
  integerOnly: {
    type: Number,
    get: v => Math.round(v),
    set: v => Math.round(v),
    alias: "i"
  }
});

var NumberType = mongoose.model("Number", numberSchema);

var doc = new NumberType();
```

The problem was: **I was defining a type**, namely `Number`, that *already exists in mongoose*.

It makes me wonder why mongoose would have a sample in their tutorial with such a primitive error: I was shadowing the Number type, it is textbook error.

It makes me think that I am missing something since I am trying to learn new tricks in mongoose, and I was unable to run the example the way they provided.